# React Native Camera - How to make capture button stick to one side of phone screen?

Tags: react-native

In Camera screen shown below I have a touchable to capture the image. The requirement is to make this stick to bottom of the phone. When user changes orientation to landscape mode touchable should not change its position  (so that that user can click with right hand fingers). How to make this touchable doesn't change it's position on change of orientation.

[image]

Code to render the camera and button is as below:

```
renderCamera() {
        return (
            <Camera
                ref={(cam) => {
                    this.camera = cam;
                } }
                style={styles.preview}
                aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
                captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk} >

                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={styles.capture}
                    onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
                    underlayColor={constant.COLOR_PRIMARY}
                    >
                    <View />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </Camera>
        );
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    },

    capture: {
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 35,
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: constant.COLOR_PRIMARY,
        backgroundColor: constant.COLOR_PRIMARY,
        marginBottom: 15
    },
    preview: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }

});
```

I tried to lock the orientation(using React-Native-Orientation-Lock)  in this screen but this added some other impact. So I am not looking into other solutions.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **react-native-camera** plugin

You can try something like shown in the issue [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1570)

Here is an [example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md) where you can update camera orientation in the function

```
takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = {
            orientation:'portrait',
            forceUpOrientation: true, 
            quality: 0.20, 
            base64: true 
        };
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
        return data
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using 
[React-Native-Orientation-Lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker%20.)

It is a react-native module that can listen on orientation changing of device, get current orientation, lock to preferred orientation. (cross-platform support).

Comment: I hope this will help you.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, we had tried using  Orientation-Lock package, but we had trouble in other screen(side effects) of wrong orientation.